# Why can't I call this method of a child object?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, object

Here, I've got a method (ToggleMovingUp) and it's a public void inside the Character Object, which inherits from "Sprite2D"

```
public void ToggleMovingUp() 
    {
        if (this.MovingUp == false) 
        {
            MovingUp = true;
        }
        else 
        {
            MovingUp = false;
        }


        
    }
```

- 

```
public class Sprite2D
{
    public Vector2 Position = null;
    public Vector2 Scale = null;
    public string Directory = "";
    public string Tag = "";
    public Bitmap Sprite = null;

    public Sprite2D(Vector2 Position, Vector2 Scale, string Directory, string Tag)
    {
        this.Position = Position;
        this.Scale = Scale;
        this.Directory = Directory;
        this.Tag = Tag;
        Image tmp = Image.FromFile($"Assets/Sprites/{Directory}.png");



        Bitmap sprite = new Bitmap(tmp);
        Sprite = sprite;
        
        

        Log.Info("Shape2D{0} - Has been registered");

        ExpressedEngine.RegisterSprite(this);

    }
```

Now the base Sprite2D object has its own public bool IsColliding

```
public bool IsColliding(Sprite2D a, Sprite2D b) 
    {
        if(a.Position.X <= b.Position.X &&
            a.Scale.X >= b.Scale.X &&
            a.Position.Y <= b.Position.Y &&
            a.Scale.Y >= b.Scale.Y) 
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

and when i create an instance of Character, i can call this method just fine but when i try to call a method from the child object (Character) it still tells me: [Sprite2D does not contain a definition for 'ToggleMovingUp...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGjLa.png)

```
player = new Character(new Vector2(StartPositionX, StartPositionY), new Vector2(25, 25), "Test Sprite/Still", "Player", 1);
```

.

```
if (up) 
        {
            player.Position.Y -= 1f;
            player.ToggleMovingUp();
        }
```

Comment: Nowhere in the code shown are you trying to call the `ToggleMovingUp` method.  Please provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: By the way, your first method can contain the single line `MovingUp = !MovingUp;`. The optimizer probably figures that out, but still, shorter code is better code.

Comment: `Character` inherits from `Sprite2D`. `Character` implements `ToggleMovingUp`. You want to call `ToggleMovingUp` in `Sprite2D` code. That's impossible. `Sprite2D` does not have that method implemented. The compiler is telling the truth. Why don't you move the method to `Sprite2D`?

Comment: The simple answer is that when you call `player.ToggleMovingUp();` the `player` variable must be of type `Sprite2D` not `Character` as you expect. Compilers dont make a mistake here, humans do.

Comment: @Dialecticus So is it just not possible to have a child object with unique methods then or am I misunderstanding. At the very least I can't move the method to Sprite2D because the MovingUp variable is unique to Character and those unique parameters are the reason i made Character in the first place.

Comment: @EpicGaia if `ToggleMovingUp` is unique to `Character` then the code that wants to call `ToggleMovingUp` must work with `Character` instead of with `Sprite2D`.

Comment: There is a father before a son. A son can inherit his father, but a father cannot inherit his son. As far as the relationship between the parent class and the child class is concerned, the parent class is not allowed to call the method of the child class.

Answer (score 0):

The `ToggleMovingUp` method is not defined in your `Sprite2D` `class`.

In order to call that method you'll either have to cast your `Sprite2D` instance to a `Character` or define the `ToggleMovingUp` method on your `Sprite2D` `class`.

If you implement the `ToggleMovingUp` method in your `Sprite2D` `class` you can provide a default implementation which can be overridden in derived classes.

Below is a simplified example of how to accomplish this with casting.

```
class Sprite2D { }

class Character : Sprite2D
{
    public bool MovingUp { get; private set; }

    public void ToggleMovingUp( ) => 
        MovingUp = !MovingUp;
}

static void Main( string[ ] _ )
{
    Sprite2D sprite = new Character( );
    
    // Safely try to cast sprite to Character with the 'is' operator.
    if ( sprite is Character character1 )            
        character1.ToggleMovingUp( ); 

   // Or you can use the 'as' operator to safely cast.
   var character2 = sprite as Character;
   if ( character2 is not null )
       character2.ToggleMovingUp( );

   // Or you can just use a C style cast. In this case if the sprite is not
   // a Character it will throw an exception.
   var character3 = ( Character )sprite;
   character3.ToggleMovingUp( );
}
```